# How can I grab the URL after a redirect?

Tags: javascript, instagram-api

I am using window.location.replace to direct user to an external service (Instagram). Once they login Instagram will redirect them and then I need to grab an authentication code from URL Instagram directed them to (the code is actually part of the URL). I am using window.location.href but it just grabs the location of the the HTML file instead of the URL. How can I get it to read the URL instead?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly... `window.location.replace` redirects the entire site, you have no control over anything and the javascript from your page stops executing as soon as the page is refreshed or left. This whole thing also seems pretty sketchy, why do you need to take the user's authentication code?

Comment: That's just how the API works. The page basically asks the user to give us permission to view their profile etc and once they agree the authentication code can be used to view that information. I presumed that I was still in control however since I can execute further window.location.replace's. Unless it just redirects to the last one.

Comment: You're only in control as long as the user is on the page. The closest thing is `var w = window.open('http://url.com')` and then something like `w.location.href`. I don't think that would even work though because it's a different domain. I am 100% sure an API wouldn't require you to steal an authentication code from a user. Make sure you read the documentation and understand what you're doing.

Comment: This is the only purpose of the authentication code. It's got nothing to do with passwords etc and just allows us to access information from their profile that there have agreed to letting us access. It is explained [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/)

Comment: I don't think you understood it correctly. From what I'm reading it seems like you redirect to the url, and then it redirects back to the redirect-uri that you set, with the GET parameter "code=...". So if your redirect uri is "http://mywebsite.com/instagram", it'll redirect the user to "http://mywebsite.com/instagram?code=abcdefg". It then tells you in step 3 that you need to send a POST request with the code you just got, and also your api client id, secret, and redirect uri. Please make sure to read more closely next time before asking.

Comment: "Once a user authorizes your application, we issue a redirect to your redirect_uri with a code parameter to use in step three." - the user is redirected back to *your* site after authorization, this is sometimes also called the "callback" URL. There's no need to keep track of the URL with your own code like you describe.

Comment: I have no site. This is supposed to be client side. I am trying to do the implicit flow described on the instagram API. I am trying to do this all in Javascript